# Swipe to remove on UIPickerView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uipickerview

Is there a way to implement a "swipe to remove" action on `UIPickerView`, just like it's done with `UITableViewController`?

I've been searching for this for some time, but have no solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIPickerView` objects are not editable. When in doubt, check the documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html

However, there's no reason why you couldn't make a custom UIPickerView using a `UITableViewController` and a bit of clever code to figure out which cell is in the middle and properly highlight it.

Comment: thank u for the answer! i actually don't need cell highlighting, and my pickerview should actually act just like tableview in terms of actions. but the only problem is how to make them visually look alike

Comment: Please mark this answer as correct if you end up finding it to be useful. You're welcome!